# Right Triangle calculations in C#

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

Long time since high school.  If I have a right triangle, and know angle A, I'd like to work out the length of the side opposite it.  The c# cookbook page on this (http://www.gibmonks.com/c_sharp/csharpckbk2-CHP-1-SECT-14.html) suggests:

oppositeSide = Math.Sin(theta) * hypotenuse;

Assuming angle A (theta) is 45, and hypotenuse is 10 units long, this code gives me a result of 8.51.  At least 4 online triangle solvers give me an answer of 7.07 however ( eg http://www.cleavebooks.co.uk/scol/calrtri.htm, and http://www.endmemo.com/geometry/triangle.php).  This gives me serious doubts!

I'm not au fait enough in trig to see which is accurate, but I'd probably favour the internet calculators.

Can anyone assist on the correct formula to do this, or point me toward a useful c# right triangle solver class?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin.aspx), the value of `theta` must be in radians. It looks like the online solvers you're using are interpreting `theta` in degrees.

You can convert from degrees to radians as follows:

```
theta = theta * Math.PI/180
```

Comment: You are right, thanks.  I'll mark this as the answer when the time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the angle in degrees, but the `Math.Sin` method takes radians.

You can convert degrees to radians using `theta * 2 * PI / 360`:

```
oppositeSide = Math.Sin(theta * 2.0 * Math.PI / 360.0) * hypotenuse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, for a right-angle triangle with one other angle known of 45deg, the 2 remaining sides are of equal length, and you can also calculate their lengths using this formula;

```
(a*a) + (b*b) = (c*c)
```

So, in this case;

```
(a*a) * (a*a) = (10*10)

(a*a) * (a*a) = 100

(a*a) = 100 / 2

a = sqrt(50)
```

Just as a another way to help you verify the result in this unique case, and prove that ~7.07 is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

The sine of 45 degrees is .707.  Your calculations are incorrect.

Comment: I'm directly applying the formula as shown above, using the standard .net math classes, so any guidance as to why it returns this value and what the correct code is would be appreciated.  cheers